# Shell script taking me inside the server

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I need to check if uptime of server is less than 1 day, if yes then I need some information like cpuinfo meminfo. Script is:

```
    for SERVER in $( cat /home/mysql/scripts/USER_SCRIPTS/patching_serverlist.txt); do
ping -c 3 $SERVER > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
        echo "$SERVER is down" >> /home/mysql/scripts/USER_SCRIPTS/pre_patching_result.txt
else
        ssh -q mysql@$SERVER 
        check_uptime
        echo $days
        if [ days < 1 ]
        then
echo -n "Hostname: "
ssh -q mysql@$SERVER hostname >> /home/mysql/scripts/USER_SCRIPTS/pre_patching_result.txt
```

What it does it takes me inside the server, i.e. i actually ssh to server, check_uptime is a function to calculate days.

The problem is, when I execute this script, I get inside the server from console, so I have to type `exit`, to exit from server when the script completes. I just want to run the function and get out. How not to get in and run the function?

Comment: But what's the question?

Comment: Problem is when I execute this script it I get inside the server from console so i have to type exit, to exit from server the script completes, I just want to run the function and  get out

Comment: `ssh -q mysql@$SERVER` this command takes you inside the server

Comment: how not to get in and run the function?

Comment: Please update your question with the details in the future. See my edit above.

Comment: Where is the function defined? In your script? On the server?

Comment: function is defined in script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a non-interactive login, in the same way you do later in the script to execute `hostname` on the remote machine:

```
days=$(ssh -q mysql@$SERVER /path/to/check_uptime)
```